# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. after udtaing sdk to sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

Tags: flutter, dart

I updated to the latest flutter version but now when I run my old project I get the error, There was an error with the firebase messaging as I updated my pubspec.yaml I was asked to update the SDK to 2.16.0<3.0.0, After doing as suggested now I run into this problem which I have no clue to solve

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 421

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

so I opened up the file that was causing the error, in the flutter.gradle file 421 is pointing out to this

```
getPluginList().each { plugin ->
                Project pluginProject = project.rootProject.findProject(plugin.key)
                pluginProject.afterEvaluate {
                    int pluginCompileSdkVersion = pluginProject.android.compileSdkVersion.substring(8) as int
                    maxPluginCompileSdkVersion = Math.max(pluginCompileSdkVersion, maxPluginCompileSdkVersion)
```

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.nepali.drivers"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //en
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and here is the flutter doctor

```
PS C:\Users\pannam\Desktop\Flutter Tutorial\drivers_app_null_safety> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
    ! Device 1WMHH865ST1315 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
PS C:\Users\pannam\Desktop\Flutter Tutorial\drivers_app_null_safety>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade flutter sdk to sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" and do not update firebase message to the last version.